# App is crashing on launch in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

Our app is got rejected by Apple due to weird crash in iPad. We are not able to reproduce this. Crash is happening when launching app in iPad(iOS8). This is what we got from the crashlytics

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  fullhouse                      0x000000010021f4c0 specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (FHAppDelegate.swift:118)
1  fullhouse                      0x000000010021c734 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (FHAppDelegate.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x0000000188036f78 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 404
3  UIKit                          0x000000018824e654 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2376
4  UIKit                          0x0000000188251008 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1504
5  UIKit                          0x000000018824f578 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 184
6  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018bd813c8 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 32
7  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001834fffc8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
8  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001834ff0d0 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001834fd6f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1756
10 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183428f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
11 UIKit                          0x0000000188030224 -[UIApplication _run] + 552
12 UIKit                          0x000000018802ad94 UIApplicationMain + 1488
13 fullhouse                      0x000000010021e15c main (FHAppDelegate.swift:17)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001958bea08 start + 4
```

Stil we cant identified the culprit from this log. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** - Adding `didFinishLaunching` method

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

#if DEBUGSETTINGS
        setDebugDefaults()
#endif

        initGoogleAnalytics()

        var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        //Set navbar background Image
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Utility.colorWithRGB(254, g: 93, b: 89)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

#if DEVENVIRONMENT
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(FHStringConstants.GooglePlaces.TEST_API_KEY)
#else
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(FHStringConstants.GooglePlaces.PRODCUTION_API_KEY)
#endif

        var pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = Utility.colorWithHex(0x8b5b62, alpha: 1.0)
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Utility.colorWithHex(0xfb5e5d, alpha: 1.0)
        pageControl.backgroundColor = Utility.colorWithHex(0x40404a, alpha: 1.0)//UIColor(red: 72/255.0, green: 162/255.0, blue: 131/255.0, alpha: 1.0)


        Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("\(FHStringConstants.Crashlytics.API_KEY)")

       UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

        if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 22) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : Utility.adjustFontToIphoneDevice(font), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

        }

        if let barItemFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 14) {
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : Utility.adjustFontToIphoneDevice(barItemFont), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

        let segmentControlAttribute = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 14.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(segmentControlAttribute as [NSObject : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var rootViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialViewController") as! FHViewController

        self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController

        checkNetworkConnectivity()
        Appboy.startWithApiKey(FHStringConstants.AppBoyConstants.apiKey, inApplication:application, withLaunchOptions:launchOptions)

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }
```

Comment: What code is at line 118 of your `FHAppDelegate.swift` file?

Comment: @Paulw11 Which is the return statement of `application didFinishLaunching` method `return true`

Comment: Well, something is going wrong in your app delegate. Perhaps you could show your `didFinishLaunching` method

Comment: Yes, i have added. please have a look

Comment: Any luck? I have the exact problem as yours. The crash report points to the "return true" of the application didFinishLaunching method...

Comment: Did you find how to solve this problem? I got the exact same one on my iPad (iOS 8) but not on iPad (iOS 9)